# Is it possible to use DocuSign API to export Organization Bulk Action envelope reports?

Tags: docusignapi

From the Organization Admin Bulk Actions Envelope Reports is it possible use the API's to export the reports?

Comment: is this a report that's part of DocuSign Monitor?

Comment: I looking into DocuSign Monitoring as a option

Comment: https://docs.docusign.com/supportdocs/pdf/docusign-monitor.pdf does this help?